# Smallest area that can be formed by 3 non intersecting diagonal of a hexagon

Tags: geometry

We have a regular hexagon: a polygon with six sides, in which all internal angles have 120 degrees and length is the 5 cm of each side. We are going to draw three non-intersecting diagonals in some way. These will divide the hexagon into four triangles. We will then compute their areas. Find the smallest of those areas.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Acc. To my solution smallest triangle is with sides 5,5,10(diagonal of hexagon =2x sides), but my answer is wrong

Comment: Why did you delete your attempts? Without your attempts this topic would be deleted.

Comment: Because they are lame and embarrassing.

Comment: OK. If you think so...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $ABCDEF$ be our hexagon and $O$ be a circumcircle of the hexagon.

Thus, the radius of the circle is equal to $5$ and $\Delta AFE\cong\Delta AOE,$ which gives $$S_{\Delta AFE}=\frac{1}{2}S_{\Delta AED}$$ and since $\Delta AFE\cong \Delta ABC$ and $\Delta AED\cong ACD,$ we see that $S_{\Delta AFE}$ is a need area.

Id est, $$S_{\Delta AFE}=\frac{5\cdot5\cdot\sin120^{\circ}}{2}=\frac{25\sqrt3}{4}$$ gives the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Tyler Lewandowski You are welcome!

Comment: You cannot answer a question, obtain the answer accepted, and then vote to close the question!

Comment: @Christian Blatter The topic starter deleted his attempts and does not want to restore it. See please better the history of this topic. I think, very bad it's this: Not understand what happens and to down-vote a right solution.